# how to change font size of active tick when hovered

Tags: lightningchart

I am able to format the cursor tick by following code

```
 chart[id].getDefaultAxisX().setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.Numeric, (ticks) =>
      ticks
        .setFormattingFunction((value) => {
          return value;
        })
        .setMajorTickStyle((tickStyle) => tickStyle.setLabelFont((font) => font.setSize(8)))
        .setCursorFormatter((value) => {
          var temp = value > 1 ? value - 1 : value;
          return formatDateTime(dateHolder[id][Math.round(temp)], 0);
        })
    );
```

i am able to change other ticks fonts by using setMajorTickStyle , but when i hover line series.. the active ticks are too big.. how to reduce its font size.also how to change the color of it.